# How to draw the following GERT network node diagram using tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw the following nodes in tikz, Kindly help me.
[image]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). Questions about how to draw specific graphics that just post an image of the desired result are really not reasonable questions to ask on the site. Please post a minimal compilable document showing that you've tried to produce the image and then people will be happy to help you with any specific problems you may have.  See [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) for what needs to go into such a document.

Comment: Also, going through the [TikZ and PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf) will answer a lot of your questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some code to start with. It uses a `semicircle` shape which is completed according the symbol you want.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=2mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}

\begin{document}
\tikzset{
    mynode/.style={draw, semicircle, shape border rotate=90, minimum width=2cm, 
        append after command={
            \pgfextra \draw (\tikzlastnode.chord center)--(\tikzlastnode.west); \endpgfextra}
            }
    }

\begin{tikzpicture}

\node[mynode, anchor=chord center, ] (a) at (0,0) {};
\draw ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]a.arc end)--([xshift=1cm]a.chord center) coordinate (a-vertex)--([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]a.arc start);

\node[mynode, right=3cm of a-vertex] (b) {};
\draw ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]b.arc start) arc[start angle=90, end angle=3, radius=1cm] --++(90:5mm);
\draw ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]b.arc end) arc[start angle=-90, end angle=-3, radius=1cm] --++(-90:5mm);

\node[mynode, below right=2.5cm and 2.7cm of a-vertex] (c) {};
\draw ([yshift=-.5\pgflinewidth]c.arc start) arc[start angle=90, end angle=-90, radius=1cm];

\draw[-latex] (a-vertex)--node[above]{A} node[below]{0.3} (b.west);
\draw[-latex] (a-vertex)--node[above right]{B} node[below left]{0.7} (c.west);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Ignasi. The code works very well after I insert \usepackage{tikz} in the preamble of your code. Thank you.

Comment: @RameshKannan: Glad to help you. I didn't inserted `\usepackage{tikz}` in my code because `tikz` option in `standalone.cls` already does it. If you use any other class (`article`, `book`, ...) you have to include it.